# Processing: transparent image over curves

Tags: image, png, jpeg, processing, transparent

Im new to Processing. I would like to put a .jpg or .png over curves and ellipses, so that they can see only where the image is transparent. 
My code is below. The problem with it is that the transparent area is not fully transparent, but transparent white and the not-transparent parts have also decreased opacity.

```
    PImage img;

    void setup() {
      size(300,500);
      frameRate(30); 
      strokeWeight(4);   
      img = loadImage("sziluettmeret.jpg"); 
    }

   void draw() {
        background(0, 50, 70);  
        stroke(0,70,90);
        noFill();
        beginShape();
        curveVertex(-100,  -100);
        curveVertex(10, 10);
        curveVertex(250,  250);
        curveVertex(300,  300);
        endShape();

       fill(255);
       ellipse(20 ,20,15,15);

       noFill();
       tint(255, 100);
       image(img, 0, 0);
    }
```

---

UPDATE:

I have this in my code:

```
    loadPixels();
    for(int i=0; i < img.pixels.length; i++) {
    tmpColor = img.pixels[i];
    tmpRed = red(tmpColor);
    tmpGreen = blue(tmpColor);
    tmpBlue = green(tmpColor);
    tmpAlpha = 255 - ((tmpRed + tmpGreen + tmpBlue)/3);
    img.pixels[i] = color(2*tmpRed,tmpGreen/2,tmpBlue,0); 
    if(0xFFFFFF == tmpColor)


      }
     updatePixels();
```

The picture does not become transparent. (But it becomes purple, so the loop runs on every pixel for sure)

Comment: "so that they can see only where the image is transparent." Who can see what? Do you want the image to be seen inside the draw only? Maybe a mask? Please make yourself more clear.

Answer (score 1):

tint() doesn't do greenscreening. It'll recolor your image (if you use a non-neutral colour), and set the mix transparancy, so with tint(255,100), you effective gave the image an opacity of (approximately) 0.39

If you want to do greenscreening (or in your case, whitescreening), you want to run through the image's pixels when you load the image, then set opacity to 0 whenever r/g/b are 255, effectively "removing" all your white pixels.

Comment: but how do I read the color of a pixel? especially, how do i read the rgb information?

Comment: that's what http://processing.org/reference is for, it lists all the functions you need =)

Comment: Right now I have this in my code, and this does not work:
          loadPixels();
           for(int i=0; i < img.pixels.length; i++) {
             tmpColor = img.pixels[i];
    tmpRed = red(tmpColor);
    tmpGreen = blue(tmpColor);
    tmpBlue = green(tmpColor);
    tmpAlpha = 255 - ((tmpRed + tmpGreen + tmpBlue)/3);
    img.pixels[i] = color(2*tmpRed,tmpGreen/2,tmpBlue,1); 
//    if(0xFFFFFF == tmpColor)
//    {
//    img.pixels[i] = color(0,0,0,0);
//    } 
  
  }
 updatePixels();